# How to get the full referrer url when viewing real-time google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When viewing real-time analytics, how do we display the full url in the referrals section?  I've seen some answers here and on various forums/blogs but they appear to be outdated.

I want to simply click on the link to see the page that is referring traffic (assuming it's public).

Update

Real-time would be nice, but if there's a way I can set up an easy way to view all referrals with full URLs within the dashboard, that would be nice as well.  I'm looking for clear, unambiguous instructions here to provide value to future readers looking for the same thing.

[image]

Comment: Due the limitation of real time report (it's highly limited report) it's not possible get this data. You can do some work around but you will pollute your data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the "Top Referrals" link you get a list with both the referrer base url and the path on that website.  In the "Referral Path" column there is a link on the right side.
[image]